# Using Yeoman programmatically inside nodejs project

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to use an yeoman generator inside a NodeJS project

I installed `yeoman-generator`and `generator-git` (the generator that I want use) as locally dependency, and, at this moment my code is like this:

```
var env = require('yeoman-generator')();
var path = require('path');
var gitGenerator = require('generator-git');
var workingDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'install_here/');
generator = env.create(gitGenerator);
```

obviously the last line doesn't work and doesn't generate the scaffold.

The question: How to?

Importantly, I want to stay in local dependency level!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@simon-boudrias's solution does work, but after I changed the `process.chdir()`, `this.templatePath()` and `this.destinationPath()` returns same path.

I could have use this.sourcePath() to tweak the template path, but having to change this to each yeoman generator is not so useful. After digging to yo-cli, I found the following works without affecting the path.

```
var env = require('yeoman-environment').createEnv();

env.lookup(function() {
    env.run('generator-name');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`env.create()` only instantiate a generator - it doesn't run it.

To run it, you could call `generator.run()`. But that's not ideal.

The best way IMO would be this way:

```
var path = require('path');
var env = require('yeoman-generator')();
var gitGenerator = require('generator-git');

// Optionnal: look every generator in your system. That'll allow composition if needed:
// env.lookup();

env.registerStub(gitGenerator, 'git:app');
env.run('git:app');
```

If necessary, make sure to `process.chdir()` in the right directory before launching your generator.

Relevant documentation on the Yeoman Environment class can be found here: http://yeoman.io/environment/Environment.html

Also see: http://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html

Comment: Awesome! But exist a little problem... the generator try to load the templates from the path of the project, and of course, crashed: 


`fs.js:432 return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode); ^ Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/username/Downloads/testGenerators/templates/_editorconfi‌​g'`

When the files are in `node_modules/generator-git/app/templates`
How change the path of the generator?
(yea, with process.chdir(), but how)

Comment: You seems to be doing some black magic. Maybe review the base of your concept and simplify it to work better with the actual API? You can change the template dir using `this.sourceRoot('path/')`

Answer (score 1):

> The `yeoman-test` module is also very useful if you want to pass predefined answers to your prompts. This worked for me.

```
var yeomanTest = require('yeoman-test');
var answers = require('from/some/file.json');

var context = yeomanTest.run(path.resolve('path/to/generator'));
context.settings.tmpdir = false; // don't run in tempdir
context.withGenerators([
  'paths/to/subgenerators',
  'more/of/them'
])
.withOptions({ // execute with options
  'skip-install': true,
  'skip-sdk': true
})
.withPrompts(answers)  // answer prompts
.on('end', function () {
  // do some stuff here
});
```